# Installing CUDA in GCP VM instance ( Debian 10.x)

Tags: gpu, cuda, google-compute-engine

I am just coming up to speed with GPU  & CUDA and going around in circles.
My GPU is Nvidia Tesla T4. However, Google documentation is lacking
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu#ubuntu-driver-steps
, as it does not help me understand which driver to install for my instance ( Debian 10.x). I tried installing drivers Ubuntu 20.4 only to realize later on that Debian 10.x maps to Ubuntu 18.x.

I get an error:

```
cuda : Depends: cuda-11-1 (>= 11.1.0) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any pointers to get me going ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is from two years ago but in case it helps someone else facing the same issue, I came across the same problem recently and I solved it by using the a cuda toolkit docker image from the nvidia docker hub (https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda) because debian OS is not supported by cuda([https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2135/~/which-operating-systems-are-supported-by-cuda%3F](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2135/%7E/which-operating-systems-are-supported-by-cuda%3F)). For this to work though, the appropriate driver for your gpu (which you can check from here https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) and also, depending on your docker version, either nvidia-docker2 or nvidia-container-runtime must be also be installed on the host system.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1162847)